# How to know whether a user has subscribed to a topic in FCM?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to know wether we have already subscriped to a topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: use `SharePreferences`.

Comment: I would too recommend sharedPref. There is an onComplete Listener that returns Successful if the subscription is done. I would save that to SharedPreferences. Or still if its that important to the Users Node in FirebaseRealTimeDb. Simplest way to check from he Clients side

Answer (score 3):

You can get token

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceID.getToken();
Log.d(TAG,token);
```

and do a Get to  https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/token

If using curl

```
curl -X Get -H"Authorization:key=serverAPIkey" "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/token?details=true"
```

to see all of the device's subscribed topics

> Find out details about a client app instance's subscriptions, including each topic name and subscribe date. See [get information about app instances](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances)

Comment: Skyler is correct, but there is no way to do this from the client side. Note however that subscribing multiple times is not harmful. So when you should be able to subscribe/unsubscribe when you want to.

Comment: I can get a token even if i am subscribed to a different topic