# How to check how many topics has been subscribed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to identify how many topics a single device is subscribed to. Then I found and followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855461/how-to-know-subscriped-to-a-topic-in-fcm). I don't know if I follow it right because i receive this message

```
{"error":"MissingAuthorization"}"
```

Here are the steps:

1. Get token from the device
2. Generate a URL: `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<paste token here>`
3. Copy-paste the URL to the browser
4. Get the response.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: It's saying that there is no Authorization specified. Are you sure you're including the `Authorization:key=<Server API key here>` in your request?

Comment: what request? where should i initialize the request?

Comment: Try it using cURL format shown in the post you linked.

Comment: how to execute curl?

Comment: is there any other method instead of using terminal?because i'm using windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353

Comment: Thanks your sir, now i can access.

Comment: Hi @khoi just wanted to ask you to accept the answer so that your post will be tagged as Already Answered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that there is no authorization specified. Make sure you're including the `Authorization:key=<Server API key here>` in your request, where the Server Key is the one found in your Firebase Console, under *Cloud Messaing* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this how you check Add the KEY=

U forgetting to put the Authorization starting with "KEY=BLALALALALA"

Authorization [image]