# Firebase: Get list of users subscribed to a topic

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Is there a way to, using the Firebase Admin SDK for Java, get a list of all registration tokens that are subscribed to a given topic?

If not, is there a way to get that information using the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to get a list of the tokens that are subscribed to a specific topic.

See:

- [Count subscribers of a topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851105/count-subscribers-of-a-topic-in-firebase-cloud-messaging)
- [How to know whether a user has subscribed to a topic in FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855461/how-to-know-whether-a-user-has-subscribed-to-a-topic-in-fcm)
- [List of clients who have registered for a topic in FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592342/list-of-clients-who-have-registered-for-a-topic-in-fcm)

Comment: Thank you! Was hoping I wouldn't need to maintain the list manually in my database.